# Which one is correct: 'escaped' or 'escaped from'?

Tags: phrase-usage

I have two sub-questions regarding `escape` v/s `escape from`.

- Escaping from a place:

> He (escaped / escaped from) prison.
>   
>   I can guess that `He escaped from prison.` is correct, but is `He escaped prison.` also correct?

- Escaping from a person:

> He (escaped / escaped from) Agent Hanratty.
>   
>   Here, both "feel" wrong! Is either or both of these correct? If not, then what is the correct phrase to express this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *from* is a prepositional term that is used to mark a starting point in time or space.  If your subject was once in prison or if he was once caught by Agent Hanratty, you would state  *"escaped from"* to indicate that the subject, at some specific point in time, *"escaped"* his existing state of captivity.

To state that your subject *"escaped prison"* or *"escaped Agent Hanratty"* could also be correct.  In this context, the implication is that your subject was nearly sent to prison or that Agent Hanratty *almost* caught the subject.  Since captivity never occurred, we state that your subject *"escaped"* a circumstance that could have happened.

Since the subject was never held captive, there was never a point in time which the term *from* can reference. Thus, *from* is omitted.

**However,** English is often a tricky language.  It isn't uncommon for news headlines to leave out some prepositional terms for the sake of brevity.  For instance, a newspaper may run a front-page articles with the headline, *"John Doe Escapes Prison!"*

Did John Doe escape prison by being acquitted of a court accusation? Did he break out and flee from a prison complex?  It is impossible to know without reading the story and gaining further context.  This is because newspapers and news sites will quite often omit the word *from* for the sake of saving a bit of headline space.

This may seem inconsequential.  However, often what "feels" right about a spoken language is what is commonly heard or read.  If you frequently read headlines and news articles, brevity will feel correct.

Comment: I searched [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) for `escaped from prison` (47 results) and `escaped prison` (4 results).  All four of the latter were used to mean someone who escaped **from** prison, and none of the four were from headlines.  Although this is a small sample size, I think (tentatively) that *escaped prison* most commonly means the same thing as *escaped from prison*.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it all depends which context you are talking in. Okay, I found something good for this.

WordWeb has better clarification on the usage of this verb (escape):

> 1- Run away from confinement (The convicted murderer escaped **from** a high security prision).
>   
>   2 - Fail to experience (Fortunately, I escaped the hurricane). Note, there's no *from* used here.
>   
> 3 - Escape potentially unpleasant consequences, get **away** with a forbidden action (She escapes **with** murder!).
>   
> 4 - Be incomprehensible to; escape understanding by (What you are seeing in him escapes me).
>   
> 5 - Remove oneself from a familiar environment, usually for pleasure or diversion (We escaped to our summer house for a few days). Note the use of *to*.

The word *escape* is not always used to describe *getting away*. **WW** mentions it further...

> 6 - Issue or leak, as from a small opening (Gas escaped **into** the bedroom)

From these examples, it seems that *He escaped **from** prison is correct.*

Comment: "She escapes with murder" is not idiomatic English. Could you provide a link to where you found these examples?

Comment: I have installed a WordWeb Pro in my PC/Smartphone. It showed the examples I wrote. Here is the online link for it: http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/ESCAPED

Comment: As The Photon says, *escapes with murder* is not idiomatic.  I'm not sure most native speakers would understand it, though I can imagine some people being able to figure it out.